# Is the lone electron pair of an amide nitrogen part of the π system when building a Hückel matrix?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, resonance, aromaticity

Is the lone electron pair of the nitrogen atom part of the conjugated π system in the α,β-unsaturated amide pictured below?

[image: acrylamide]

Is there a general rule for choosing when to include a nitrogen atom in a Hückel matrix?

Comment: I have edited your post for clarity. At the risk of incurring ill-will from our German folks, I have replaced your "ue" (yes, it's correct; no, most people don't know that) in the title and added back the umlaut in the text.

Comment: Pro tip: [get to know a compose key](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4766/whats-the-best-alternative-to-mathjax-in-titles-and-for-one-off-symbols/4770#4770) and never fear Unicode German or Greek letters again with simple and intuitive keystrokes like `RAlt` `"` `u` for letter ü or `RAlt` `*` `p` for letter π (cc @ToddMinehardt).

Comment: @ToddMinehardt So to get it right - is or is not **ue** acceptable EN transcription  for  DE **ü** ? ( I guess such transcriptions would get hard time for CZ ones ) // An alternative is to have a short list of frequent UC characters and codes, performing either copy/paste either invoking unicode insertion by the code, like `CTRL+SHIFT+U<unicode>ENTER` on Linux.

Comment: Actually I am German, so I have the ü right on my keyboard. I have just always read the "ue" spelling in English literature, so I thought I'd not confuse you with umlauts :D

Comment: I guess you can include the lone pair in the Huckel matrix, but it will probably become very difficult to solve by hand. If you have a computer, that will solve it. If you ignore the lone pair, your system is only a linear chain of p-orbitals, it will give that diagonal looking matrix (not a diagonal matrix!!) that you could solve with a pen and paper.

Comment: @Poutnik - I assumed Charles was German and/or was helping us optimize for search engines.

Comment: @Poutnik Writing English with *occasional* extras, you might consider as keyboard layout [US *international*](https://dry.sailingissues.com/us-international-keyboard-layout.html) if characters stay Latin. Then «ü» either is alt+y, or "+u. This equally adds e.g., the µ character to your tool box, too.

Comment: @Buttonwood Thanks, it may be useful. But it may also further mess up things, if one already uses 2 or 3 layouts. Android has exceptionally small advantage here.

Answer (score 3):

Setting aside the arguments over umlauts, yes you can add the nitrogen atom to the Hückel matrix; in fact, theoretically you should do so and allow the matrix eigenfunctions and eigenvalues to decide whether the nitrogen atom in this case is really conjugated. The carbonyl oxygen can also be coupled in.

But there is a catch. Since the nitrogen or
oxygen atom has different atomic orbital energy levels from the carbon atoms, and the orbital overlap with other atoms will be different, you cannot just put in the same numbers that you would with a carbon atom there. Various estimates are available for these heteroatom parameters, for instance [this one given by Texas A&M University](https://www.chem.tamu.edu/rgroup/hughbanks/courses/673/handouts/Huckel_Heteroatom_parameters.pdf) which includes common heteroatoms for the diagonal elements and their bonds with carbon for the off-diagonal elements.

Once you have decided upon the matrix elements you can solve the matrix for its eigenfunctions (molecular orbitals) and eigenvalues (energy levels) the same way you would with an all-carbon system, but the equations will probably be more complex and require numerical methods to solve efficiently.